# Augmented graded algebras - properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be an augmented graded unital algebra over field $k$.

Define $A_+=\bigoplus\limits_{i\ge 1}A^{(i)}$.

I'm trying to show that

$\sum\limits_{i+j>k}A_+^i\otimes A_+^j=\bigcap\limits_{l+m=k}\left(A_+^{l+1}\otimes A+A\otimes A_{+}^{m+1}\right)$,

where $a\in A_+^n$ means $a=b_1...b_n$ for some $b_1,...,b_n \in A_+$

Propably it is easy, but I'm still going round in circles. Any hints how to do it in a simple way ?

EDIT: In the previous version was assumption : $A^{(0)}\cong 0$, but it seems like there was a typo in article. So, under which assumptions this statement is true ? Is it true if we assume $A^{(0)}=k$ ?

Comment: Could you provide a definition of augmented graded algebra? Also, do you really want the $0$-degree to be $0$? Is the algebra not unital?

Comment: Augmented graded algebra is an unital algebra over field $k$ with gradation (in the usual sens : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_ring#Graded_algebra ) and associated with a morphism $\varepsilon : A \rightarrow k$ ( I'm only interested in case when $k=\mathbb{C}$, but it can generalized).  Maybe it also works if we don't assume the $0$-degree to be $0$, but I need it only in such a case (it was gives as a lemma for proof of some properties of coalgebra filtering ).

Comment: In a graded unital algebra, the degree $0$ part can never be $0$ as that is the only place the unit can be.

Comment: Right. So, it seems like there is a typo in an article which I'm reading. Suppose that the $0$-degree is $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. $A$ is connected. Is then this statement true ? Or maybe, what should we assume if we want validity of this statement ?

Comment: @mikis Where is the article you are reading?

Comment: Rev.Math.Phys., Vol. 17, No.8(2005), p. 908, statement above proposition 1.19.;  'Combinatiorial Hopf algebras in Quantum Field Theory'

Comment: Is it contained in this probably rearranged version of your document? http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0408145v3.pdf

Comment: Yes, in this version it is on p.27 above prop. 5.5